# BSOD in 64 bits environment when one driver access another driver memory

Tags: 64-bit, driver

i have two driver which is SCSI driver (PCI device) and virtual NIC driver (data pass through SCSI driver).

virtual NIC driver initial state will call SCSI driver to get data which user setting. there is ok in 32 bits, but fail when i try in 64 bits environment. i am using windbg.exe to debug and get `0x0000007e` error, and detail information is

> Arg1: ffffffffc0000005, The exception code that was not handled
>
> Arg2: fffff800040c4bb9, The address that the exception occurred at
>
> Arg3: fffff880045cde88, Exception Record Address
>
> Arg4: fffff880045cd6e0, Context Record Address
>
> ### Debugging Details:
>
> EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - 0x%08lx
>
> FAULTING_IP:  nt!strncmp+49 fffff800`040c4bb9 488b01 mov rax,qword ptr [rcx]
>
> EXCEPTION_RECORD:  fffff880045cde88 -- (.exr 0xfffff880045cde88)
>
> ExceptionAddress: fffff800040c4bb9 (nt!strncmp+0x0000000000000049)
>
> ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)   ExceptionFlags: 00000000
>
> NumberParameters: 2
>   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000
>   Parameter[1]: 0000000005000020
>
> Attempt to read from address 0000000005000020

how can i access another driver memory when i am in 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

> Attempt to read from address 0000000005000020

The address is not in the kernel space. Should it be?

> There is ok in 32 bits, but fail when i try in 64 bits environment

It looks like the problem is in porting your driver to 64 bits. Access to another driver memory is the same in 32 and 64 bits.